# Should I optimize for performance or memory for mobile?

Tags: java, android

When building an app (in my case Android) should you code to optimize for performance or for memory?

For example, let's say I'm using the method findViewById(int resid).
To optimize for performance, I would simply store the view into an instance variable, so that I don't need to call it again.
To optimize for memory, I would not store this, but call this method every time I need to find that view again.

Of course, there are a plethora of other examples, but this the general idea: should you call the same method every time you need it (thereby using more processing), or save it to a variable (thereby using more memory)?

Does it matter which one I do? Is one better than the other? Thanks!

Comment: As the saying goes: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Do not worry about optimizing until you actually see an issue with battery life / memory consumption / speed. At that point there are analysis tools you can use to determine **where** to make those optimizations so you don't have to worry about every single line like this. In reality complier optimizations and caching take care of a lot of this stuff for you, which is why you wait to see where you have issues before asking questions like this

Comment: You should optimize the _readability_ and _maintainability_ of your code as the primary interest. See also Effective Java, [Item 55: Optimize judiciously](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~rodolfo/dcc030-2-11/Effective%20Java%20Item%2055.htm)

Comment: @nhouser9 so you're saying either way doesn't matter as long as its readibility is optimized?

Comment: But it does matter, but only when it matters.

Comment: @CliffordBernett Yes. I am saying make it as readable as possible **until you notice an issue**. I am not saying it never matters, I am saying don't worry about it until your code is running slow or draining battery or some other problem comes up.

Comment: You should also consider battery usage. There is no simple answer.

Comment: @nhouser9 A much-abused partial quotation. Look up the whole thing.

Comment: @EJP I have read the whole thing. I strongly believe that in this case the partial quotation applies, as the compiler and the cache will optimize out the small improvements in his example.

Comment: don't optimize the whole code. Do optimization when you write a code. Make your code efficient each time you write it. Don't wait until you've finished writing a big one. Have an optimization mindset. `Don't wait until the morrow what you can do today`

Answer (score 0):

at the risk of being down voted ....

it all of course depends, but for your example of `findViewById`, you should in general cache the result in a member variable.  The docs for `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` encourage this model.

But be careful - if your are trying to do this in a `Fragment` (eg in `onCreateView` callling `findViewById` several times and caching the results) then you'll get leaks (there are various articles about this).  The solution in this case is to null these cached references in the `onDestroyView`

Comment: Answers one specific example but I think the OP is looking for more general guidance.